# Could we please stop dupe-hammering this question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45226466/330057) has been dupe-hammered twice for two different answers, neither of which apply.

The original problem is someone is spawning some threads, spawning another thread, having the first few wait for the last one, and going on its merry way. Unfortunately for the OP, there's nothing that stops that last thread from finishing before the first few even start. So when they wait, they wait forever. A common mistake when trying to wrap your brain around exactly how concurrency works, to say the least.

But both "duplicates" that have been dupe-hammered simply do not apply. [The first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/886722/330057) reminds users that if you truly want to wait on the same object, you have to synchronize on that object. But OP is already doing this. [The second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37026/330057) reminds users the difference between `notify` and `notifyAll` which is even *further* from the problem.

By the time it was dupe-hammered, it already had two decent answers that describe the problem. It's further exacerbated by the first dupe-hammer-wielder [linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226466/java-notifyall-not-notify-all-threads/45226604#comment77419616_45226466) to a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) on "how much research effort" is necessary, which is pretty cold considering OP was able to reduce the problem to a minimally complete example that illustrated the problem.

I reopen-hammered it in response to the first dupe-hammer, but obviously cannot do it again.

tl;dr OP asked a decent question and got dumped on unfairly.

Comment: The question really needs an edit from the OP with what you have in your third paragraph.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your point, BSMP. Should OP take the time to point out why his question is valid in his question? Seems poor form to me...

Comment: Yes, the OP should explain why the duplicates aren't actually duplicates, like you just did here. The edit should get it re-opened in the re-open queue and it will prevent a third duplicate closure.

Comment: I have no idea whether this is a duplicate or not because I'm not a Java programmer, so I'll reserve judgment on that. However, there *is* a problem with your Meta question, namely that, in the "tl;dr" section, you imply that only "indecent" questions should be closed as duplicates, and that closing a question as a duplicate is "dumping on". Both of those are wrong. The question is either a duplicate or not a duplicate. The quality of the question and "being nice" have absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: Reopen vote cast. I find it in poor taste when questions get dupe-closed with incredibly generic canonicals like this. This is a specific problem not to be answered with a catch-all "here is how the tech works".

Comment: LOL, [multithreading] again.  This tag surely must hold the record for the most inappropriate, misleading, lame and/or totally incorrect answers on SO.  Then again, the questions are often pretty bad too:)

Comment: @Gimby shhh! You are hurting the site by not allowing people to find the questions others want them to see, whenever they are relevant or not.

Comment: @CodyGray You saw implications I did not make. A question that is a duplicate of an existing question is, by definition, not a decent question. And closing a question as a duplicate is not dumping on them, but closing it twice for questions that don't reasonably apply definitely is dumping on them.

Comment: *"A question that is a duplicate of an existing question is, by definition, not a decent question."* I completely disagree. There can actually be *value* in duplicates, if they present the question in a different way because they increase the odds of people finding the answer. And then there are just perfectly well-asked questions that just so happen to be duplicates because the person who asked them isn't familiar enough with the technology to be able to find the duplicate. I don't see those as "indecent" questions. I get what you're saying about "dumping" though in this particular context.